# Using Unbalanced multicolumns in beamer slides

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, multicolumn

I'm using the following code:

```
\begin{frame}[t]{Table of Contents}
     \begin{multicols*}{2}
          \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
     \end{multicols*}
\end{frame}
```

But the output I'm getting is still balanced columns. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `multicols` with beamer. Beamer has its own mechanism for columns and if you split the toc yourself, you have much more control over the result:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Table of Contents}
  \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
      \tableofcontents[sections={1-2}]
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
      \tableofcontents[sections={3-4}]
    \end{column}    
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}


\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Context}
\subsection{Justification of Study}
\subsection{Hypothesis}
\subsection{Objectives}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{Methodology}
\subsection{Study Area}
\subsection{Data}
\subsection{Tools}
\subsection{Methods}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{Results and Discussion}
\subsection{Results}
\subsection{Discussion}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusion and Perspectives}
\subsection{Conclusion}
\subsection{Perspectives}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]